# Visual Studio Code "The page is not responding"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't opens VS Code, because it keeps showing the message "The page is not responding".
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Please show a screen shot, as that doesn’t happen to everyone.

Comment: TBH, I would just try the simplest thing ever: restart the computer and launch vs code again

Comment: Thank you for all of the answers, turns out there was too much extensions running, all I had to do was uninstaling some of them